# Export data from the new Mapbox Studio

Tags: web-mapping, export, mapbox, download, vector-tiles

The [new Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) seems to have a button for downloading a style:

[image]

but not a dataset:

[image]

So, is there actually a way to export a whole dataset?

This may seem like a strange thing to do, but since the editor is now cloud-based, you don't necessarily have the source files close at hand.

The only way to download the data again seems to be to request a very large number of vector tiles, and somehow stitch them back together.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue. Though I have not found a solution yet, I describe here my unsuccessful attempt, maybe it will help someone:

I noticed that in [mapbox-gl-test-suite](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-test-suite/tree/master/render-tests/circle-blur/default) they run tests by rendering tile png images based on provided json styles (I guess it is Mapbox GL Style json) and compare the rendered and expected png files (on pixel level).

My idea was to take the piece of code which renders the png tile image but apply my own Mapbox GL Style json obtained via `Mapbox Studio > Download` as suggested by Steve.

I managed to launch the whole test suite and changed [style.json](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-test-suite/tree/master/render-tests/circle-blur/default) with my own json file, but then I run into following error:

```
ERROR (Style): Failed to load sprite: Error: Invalid protocol: mapbox:
```

The issue is that in original style.json they use following URIs to gather tiles:

```
local://tiles/{z}-{x}-{y}.vector.pbf
```

However my json style obtained from web-based Mapbox Studio has following remote-style URIs (i.e. all content is served from mapbox servers):

```
mapbox://sprites/mylogin/somehash
```

Maybe I miss some require in js to add support for such remote URIs, or maybe I am completely wrong and this is not right approach to gather tiles from web-based Mapbox Studio for offline use.

Comment: To those flagging this as "Not An Answer": Another moderator and I have both disputed those flags.  In my case I have done so because I know that this does not (claim to) provide a solution, but it is an answer that may help the asker (and later readers) find their solution.  If you do not think that such answers should be provided then I think you should downvote rather than flag.  I have upvoted this answer because I can see that it has been carefully crafted on a question that had gone unanswered for more than a month.

Comment: Hmm. This is pretty interesting info, but it's actually not addressing this question, which is how to download the *data* in bulk. Instead, it's addressing attempting to download a *rendered map*, tile by tile.

Comment: Hi, the only reason I added the text as an "answer" is that I am prohibited from adding comments to the initial (Steve')s post, due to "you must have 50 reputation to comment" (honestly I dont understand the policy, but nevermind).

Comment: concerning Steve's remark " how to download the data in bulk" - once you know how to download a single tile, it is quite easy to download plenty of them because the algorithm [to translate bounding box to z/x/y is simple](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Pseudo-code) and there are plenty of its implementations around the web.